# Write to a Parse Installation class object that is not of the current device PFInstallation iOS Swift 3 FROM CLIENT APP

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server, pfinstallation

I'm wondering if a user can read/write a row in the Parse Installation class that does not belong to their device?

I tried `PFInstallation.query()` and `PFQuery(className: "Installation")` to query the installation class to then edit and save the objects. The first method returned the following error: `Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection`. The second returned no objects in the query.

Is it impossible to write to an Installation class row other than the PFInstallation.current() of the device? Or does someone know a proper method of how to do so?

Also, I am trying to do this from a client app, WITHOUT the Master Key

First Method:

```
let query = PFInstallation.query()
    query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (rows, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            print(rows)

        } else {

            print("Error: ", error!)

        }
    })
```

Second Method:

```
let inst = PFQuery(className: "Installation")
    inst.whereKey("deviceType", equalTo: "ios")
    inst.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (rows, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for row in rows! {

                print("row: ", row)

            }

        } else {

            print("ERROR: ", error!)

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The class name is `_Installation` (All reserved table/class names start with an underscore `_`)

Allowed operations in `_Installation` ([More here](http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#security-edge-cases)):

Get  -> ignores CLP, but not ACL
Find -> master key only *
Create -> ignores CLP
Update -> ignores CLP, but not ACL **
Delete -> master key only **
Add Field -> normal behavior

> * Get requests on installations follow ACLs normally. Find requests without master key is not allowed unless you supply the installationId as a constraint.
>
> ** Update requests on installations do adhere to the ACL defined on the installation, but Delete requests are master-key-only. For more information about how installations work, check out the installations section of the REST guide.

Extra:

It's both safer and simpler to use the class name provided by the class itself rather than entering the string value.

```
// Unsafe, can lead to typos, etc.
let query = PFQuery(className: "Installation")
// Better
let query = PFQuery(className: PFInstallation.parseClassName)
// Simpler
let query = PFInstallation.query()
```